# open dropdown menu after highlighting text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get a drop-down menu to open after highlighting text on a webpage but the drop-down isn't opening. Also, I've converted the object to a string so it doesn't open when you click in the window but no text is select, should I create a DIV instead of a string?

html:

```
 <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
    <li><a href="#">comment</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">message</a></li>
  </ul>
```

js:

```
function getSelected() {
    if (window.getSelection) {
        return window.getSelection();
    }
    else if (document.getSelection) {
        return document.getSelection();
    }
    else {
        var selection = document.selection && document.selection.createRange();
        if (selection.text) {
            return selection.text;
        }
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}

var selection = getSelected();


function checkObj(){
    var a = String(selection);
  var b = a.length;
  if (b > 0){
   $('.dropdown-menu').dropdown('toggle');//this isn't working
  }
}
    $(window).mouseup(function() {
  var a = checkObj(selection);

});
```

UPDATE:
I've gottenthe menu to show but it only shows if i highlight text and then drag the pointer outside of the textbox im working in, but if I just highlight one word it doesnt work. Also, I can get the dropdown to appear right over the text i've highlighted.

http://liveweave.com/vDCkDp

Comment: https://github.com/dcondrey/highlighterWP

Answer (score 0):

`$('.dropdown-menu').dropdown('toggle');`

Isn't working since the `dropdown` function probably checks click events or something.

`$('.dropdown-menu').show();` seems to open the menu properly it requires manually writing js code to close the menu, see https://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/ for a proper way of closing elements when clicking outside of them.